# Append two of the same elements in one list to another list if a duplicate is found Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm creating a hangman game and I've run into a problem with the code and I cannot figure out how to resolve it. Basically what is happening is my code appends all the letters from a word to a list. If there are duplicate letters in the word, it will append both of the letters. In the method below that one, if the user gets the letter correct that is in the word, the letter is pushed to a list. However, if they guess the letter correctly and it is a letter that has two instances of it in the original list, then only one instance of it gets appended to the correct letters list. I feel like I'm overthinking this and it can be solved easily but I am very new to Python and just learning it and I cannot figure it out.

```
import random
from word_list import words


class Word():
    def __init__(self, chosen_word):
        self.chosen_word = chosen_word
        self.word_chars = []
        for letter in chosen_word:
            self.word_chars.append({
                "letter": letter,
                "guessed char": False
            })
        print(self.word_chars)

    def hidden_word(self):
        self.hidden_letter = ''
        for letter in self.word_chars:
            if letter['guessed char'] == True:
                self.hidden_letter += f"{letter['letter']} "
            else:
                self.hidden_letter += '_ '
        print(self.hidden_letter)


def game():
    remaining_guesses = 8
    letters_used = []
    chosen_word = random.choice(words)
    game_word = Word(chosen_word)
    correct_letters = []

    while remaining_guesses > 0:
        game_word.hidden_word()
        user = input('\nGuess a letter!\n')

        if user in letters_used:
            print('\nyou already guessed that\n')
            print(f'\nyou have {remaining_guesses} guesses left')

        elif user in chosen_word:
            print(f'\n{user} is in the word\n')
            letters_used.append(user)
            correct_letters.append(user)
            print(correct_letters)

            for letter in game_word.word_chars:
                if letter['letter'] == user:
                    letter['guessed char'] = True
                    print(f'\nyou have {remaining_guesses} guesses left')

        else:
            print(f"\n{user} is not in the word")
            remaining_guesses -= 1
            letters_used.append(user)
            print(f'\nyou have {remaining_guesses} guesses left\n')

    if remaining_guesses == 0:
        print(f'the word was {chosen_word}')
        print('\nyou lose!\n')
        return


game()
```

Example Input/Output

```
[{'letter': 'p', 'guessed char': False}, {'letter': 'e', 'guessed char': False}, {'letter': 'e', 'guessed char': False}, {'letter': 'k', 'guessed char': False}, {'letter': 'a', 'guessed char': False}, {'letter': 'b', 'guessed char': False}, {'letter': 'o', 'guessed char': False}, {'letter': 'o', 'guessed char': False}]
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

Guess a letter!
e

e is in the word

['e']

you have 8 guesses left

you have 8 guesses left
_ e e _ _ _ _ _ 

Guess a letter!
```

I've tried

```
if len(correct_letters) == len(chosen_word):
                    print('\nYou win!\n')
                    print(f'The word was {chosen_word}')
                    return
```

which doesn't end the program if there's double letter because the lengths are different. I can't use sorted or set as the lists aren't hashable.

Comment: Sorry, just realized I didn't add one. Just added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

First get the number of instances of the letter using something like.

```
Correct_Word = "peekaboo"
Correct_Letters = []
guessed_letter = 'e'
```

And then use `extend` to add the guessed letter the number of times the letter is present in the word.
For eg:- in `peekaboo` there are 2 `e`s so we have to add it 2 times in the list.

```
Correct_Letters.extend([guessed_letter]*Correct_Word.count(guessed_letter))
```

Comment: Let me recommend you put more attention to your variable naming approach. It's commin practice to keep vars names starting with lower case, while classes etc are capitalized which helps code readability. Not to mention mixing `snske_case` with `camelCase`. It's a mess to work with in any bigger project

Comment: Thank You, will try to make it my habit to use proper variable names